# Jump search with Strings

Tags: java, algorithm

i have been doing research on the jump search algorithm in an array. But i am confused on how you can use the search method with strings. Can anyone give me a link on where to look, or an example on here? Every example i have seen has been with numbers

```
public class JumpSearch
{
    public static int jumpSearch(int[] arr, int x)
    {
        int n = arr.length;
  
        int step = (int)Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
  
        int prev = 0;
        while (arr[Math.min(step, n)-1] < x)
        {
            prev = step;
            step += (int)Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
            if (prev >= n)
                return -1;
        }
  
        while (arr[prev] < x)
        {
            prev++;
  
            if (prev == Math.min(step, n))
                return -1;
        }
  
        if (arr[prev] == x)
            return prev;
  
        return -1;
    }
  
    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {
        int arr[] = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21,
                    34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610};
        int x = 55;
  
        // Find the index of 'x' using Jump Search
        int index = jumpSearch(arr, x);
  
        System.out.println("\nNumber " + x +
                            " is at index " + index);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is confusing you? Strings have a natural order just like numbers. So just like you can say that 2 > 1 you can also say that B > A.

Comment: Will it just go through the first letter? Ben > Alex ?

Comment: Just try the same with `String[] arr` and `String x`. That requires you to replace the comparison operations with `compareTo(...)` and comparing the result with 0 but it should be doable.

Comment: No, the natural order of strings is defined by their characters (the first that's greater defines which string is greater) and their length (if all matching chars are the same, the longer string is greater). Hence "Ben" > "Annabel" > "Anna" > "Alex"